# Is it safe to remove mono as VSCode is no longer need it?

Tags: dependencies, visual-studio-code

Since VSCode(0.8+) is no longer need mono dependency, is it ok to run `sudo apt-get remove mono-devel` without any problems, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That VSCode doesn't need mono is only true when you do not use it for C# development. For C# mono is still required and will be for the next couple of releases.